# Django use F() to the jsonField and there is json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: django, django-filter, django-jsonfield

this is the code

```
class Helo(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    aa = models.JSONField(null=True)
    bb = models.JSONField(null=True)
```

one example data is this:

| id | aa | bb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"p1":11 "p2": 22} | {"p1": 33, "p2": 44} |

and i run this code

```
test=Helo.filter(aa__p1__gte = F('bb__p1'))
test.count()
```

get these error message

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

i also tried the

```
test=Helo.filter(aa__p1__gte = F('bb'))
test.count()
```

and there is no error, i wonder why i cant use the

`F('bb__p1')`

Comment: Likely because the Django ORM is not that expressive enough. But using JSON blobs is usually not a good idea anyway: it violates first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: thanks! ur right, im trying to change the structure of the table now